# make: *** No rule to make target '–B'. Stop

Tags: android, cygwin

When running ndk-build -B in cygwin I got the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target '–B'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of copying and pasting that command, type it in.

```
ndk-build -B
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this answer

Comment: Editted my answer and Corrected it.